# Search table column with last character in its values

Tags: php, mysql

I have an sql query to perform,

I have a column named as `ringSetName` with entries like

```
DFWR001921S
DFWER923231
```

Etc
i want to get all entries with last character as S

I have tried using

```
SELECT * 
FROM rings
WHERE ringSetName LIKE  '%s'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried uppercase `S`? You might use a case sensitive collation

Comment: @juergend yes i have.

Comment: It should work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32e04/1. So it is something else you don't mention

Comment: There is a lot of answers... you can use RIGHT [string function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) here is [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/974ae/1) for that... GL

Comment: @juergend is correct, it should work. Can you provide any more information about what you are doing - it looks like your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe there is a blank space at the end of each of your records.

Comment: Check the collation of the table - if it is a binary (ends with _bin) then LIKE is case-sensitive.

Comment: are you sure about your last character is 'S', there may be ' ' blank chars.

 `ringSetName like '% '` this will return rows which ends with white space. Check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using uppercase `S` if you use a case-sensitive collation

```
WHERE ringSetName LIKE  '%S'
```

Otherwise it should work. See this example from [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32e04/1)

Comment: `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` is better approach. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM rings
WHERE ringSetName REGEXP '.*[sS]$'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: '.*[sS][[:blank:]]*$'  if you need to account for whitespace following

Comment: This really is overkill to just match the final character in a string, `LIKE '%s'` is much more succinct (as to why that isn't working for the OP is another question).

Comment: OP asked for uppercase S, so '%S' which works for me on his examples

Comment: The regex avoid the overhead of converting to uppercase if both are required, otherwise I agree LIKE '%S' is probably the best solution

Comment: `LIKE` is only case sensitive on binary strings, so (assuming the field isn't binary) `LIKE '%s'` will match both `snakes` and `SNAKES`.

Comment: Thanks for that info - I had forgotten, but all of the tables I use are configured to use a BIN collation which is why I needed to convert to upper

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM rings
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTRING(ringSetName,-1)) = 'S'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful, use it.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM rings
    WHERE TRIM(ringSetName) LIKE  '%s$'
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This won't work, `LIKE` doesn't use regular expressions (in MySQL at least) - this will match strings ending in a literal `s$`

Comment: remove the $, LIKE '%S' would work (need to ensure upper case)

Comment: use REGEXP instead LIKE

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM rings WHERE UPPER(ringSetName) like '%S'
LIMIT 0 , 30;

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. please [edit] your answer, use code markdown and add a short explanation, to make your answer clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM rings
WHERE ringSetName LIKE '%s' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

`_ci` means case_insensitive

also check your last character for `' '` white space situation.

If that returns some rows which has `' '` , you should trim your rows.

```
SELECT *
    FROM rings
    WHERE ringSetName LIKE '% '
```